# What are the consequences of using gnome tweak tools on elementary

Tags: release-freya, tweak-tool

What will happen if I use gnome tweak tool in elementary OS? Does it break my system?

*Please explain in detail*.

Also, can I use this `gnome-tweak` tool for changing `fonts`, `backgrounds` etc., or should I *ban* it in elementary  *completely*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNOME Tweak tool is designed for [GNOME](https://www.gnome.org/), a [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) that is not shipped with elementary OS. While elementary OS does use some of the same components and thus settings as GNOME, not everything is similar or compatible.

Installing GNOME Tweak Tool pulls in a couple of dependencies from GNOME: `gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0` and `gnome-shell-common`. These are pretty small packages and shouldn't have any noticeable effect.

Several settings will have no effect since they are meant for GNOME components. The following settings and some others will have no effect:

- Icons on Desktop
- Lock Screen background
- Any of the "Top Bar" category settings
- Workspaces

Some of the settings in GNOME Tweak tool are already exposed in the System Settings app that comes with elementary OS, such as several accessibility settings, advanced keyboard options, startup apps settings and more.

TL;DR It's technically partially usable, but keep in mind that it isn't made for elementary OS. Some stuff doesn't work correctly and some stuff doesn't work at all

Answer (score -1):

If you want you could check [these.](https://itsfoss.com/things-to-do-after-installing-elementary-os-loki/)
Section: 4. INSTALL ELEMENTARY TWEAKS IN ORDER TO INSTALL THEMES AND ICONS IN LOKI. For those on Loki, maybe it could be useful.